# Django: Formset Submit Button not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add an inlineformset to my CreateView so users can add multiple Children within the Parent form. The form generates properly but when I click the submit button nothing happens.

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ...
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    ...
```

views.py

```
class ParentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Parent
    form_class = ParentForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        Child_form = ChildFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  child_form=child_form,
                                  formset=ChildFormSet))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        child_form = ChildFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and child_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, child_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, child_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, child_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        child_form.instance = self.object
        child_form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, child_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  child_form=child_form,
                                  formset=ParentFormSet))
```

forms.py

```
class ParentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')


ChildFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Parent, Child, extra=10,
                                                       exclude=('creation', 'last_modified'), can_delete=False)
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}

    {% crispy formset %}

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: can you show your template?

Comment: Realised i missed it out. It has been added

Comment: We both have the same bug. my post is [Submit button for formset does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693617/uploading-multiple-images-in-django-for-a-single-post%22Subimit%20button%20do%20not%20work%22)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem when i put my main form body in `<table> ... </table>`

like that :

```
<form id="CreateExamForm" method="POST" enctypr="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table>
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Classe - Matière - Date</h3>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                {% crispy doc_form %}

                                {{ file_form_set.management_form }}
                                {% for f_form in file_form_set %}
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        {% crispy f_form %}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add recipe" class="submit" />
                </form>
```